# jQuery if radio button checked, validate credit card number

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I have been trying to use jQuery to validate a form (no plugins). Now I'm stuck on, when a radio button for credit cards, visa, mastercard, american express, are checked then I need to validate the credit card number using regex so that if a radio button is checked but no card number entered then there is an error msg.

I also need to validate the expiration month and year but I'm not sure where to start.

This is what I have for HTML and jQuery.

HTML:

```
         <!-- Credit card text box -->
<label for="cardNumber">Credit Card Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="cardNumber" type="text" name="cardNumber"/>
    <span id="cNhint" class="hint err-cNumber"></span><br>

           <!-- Fieldset payment radio buttons -->
<fieldset id    ="paymentMethod" data-role="paymentMethod">
<legend> Payment Method *</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="paymentType" name="credit_card"  value="None"  checked="checked" />
    <label>None</label>
  <input type="radio" id="paymentType" class="cardType cardErr" name="credit_card"  value="Visa"  />
    <label for="visa">Visa</label>
  <input type="radio" id="paymentType" class="cardType cardErr" name="credit_card"  value="MasterCard" />
    <label for="mastercard">MasterCard</label>
  <input type="radio" id="paymentType" class="cardType cardErr" name="credit_card"  value="American Express" />
    <label for="americanexpress">American Express</label>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery:

```
$cForm.submit(function(event) {
var creditCardPattern = /^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/;
            //credit card number
    var $ccNumber = $('#cardNumber');
    var $errccardNumber = $('.err-cNumber');
    var errors = 0;
      // This is not working
    if ($paymenet.is(':checked')) {
        if(!creditCardPattern.test($paymentType.val())) {
            $errpayment.append('Must contain a 13- 16 digit number with no spaces or dashes!');
            errors += 1;
            }
    }

    if(errors >0) {
        $('.error').append('Please edit the marked fields below to fix errors.');
            event.preventDefault();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your validation should automatically detect what kind of card was entered based on the number of digits, you shouldn't make your users select which card they're entering. Take a look here: http://formvalidation.io/validators/creditCard/

Comment: I'm actually hard coding this not using any form of plugin or foundation. Also by requirements I have to use a pattern in jquery to validate, no html5 input types.

Answer (score 0):

What are `$paymenet` and `$paymentType` declared as? Have you confirmed that they is picking up the elements you're expecting?

The error message you're displaying `Must contain a 13- 16 digit number with no spaces or dashes!` doesn't match the action of the regex, either. Your regex is currently checking for four groups of four digits separated by dashes.

The regex to match the error you're displaying would be `/^\d{13,16}$/`

Alternatively, you could ignore non-digits the user has entered in your check by doing this: `if(!creditCardPattern.test($paymentType.val().replace(/\D/g,''))){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned, it is unclear where $paymenet and $paymentType is cming from. Are they declared earlier?

---

I've been testing your solution a bit in a [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65p64bd3/) and it seems that your problem lies with how you select your checked radio button.

I have no problems with it when I'm selecting like this:

```
  var $creditcardVendor = $("#paymentMethod").find(":checked");
```

What is key is that the root element selected, `#paymentMethod` in this case, only contains one group of radio buttons/checkboxes. I can't find any obvious technical problem with the actual regexvalidation, so that part should work.

---

*Sidenote 1 - Your labels aren't working properly. Add `for="<some id>"` to them to decrease user frustration.*

*Sidenote 2 - Do you need the "None"-option? Since you can't have a CC without a CC vendor, you could check for selection with `$creditcardVendor.length`. If the length is zero, no checked options exist and no vendor is chosen. If it's 1, then a vendor is chosen.*